# How to let a player block (1.8.8)

Tags: plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I tried to make the player block (If you rightclick with a sword you block)
and I had the idea to use

```
player.setBlocking(true);
```

But that does'nt exist. There is only a method to check if a player is blocking but I could'nt find anything to set the Player blocking.

Method to check if Blocking:

```
player.isBlocking();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't force player to "block" (use item), check [this](https://wiki.vg/Protocol#Use_Item) for more information about Minecraft protocols.

but you can try something with

```
Bukkit.getPluginManager().callEvent(new ...Event(...));
```

But in this case only result of an action will be sent to user.